# How to add months in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi here is the query where I get data from oracle

```
Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.date_applied) Year,
       EXTRACT(Month FROM A.date_applied) Month,
       round(sum(nvl(decode(A.direction,'+',(A.quantity-a.qty_reversed)*A.cost),0))) Value
From INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST2 a
group by EXTRACT(Month FROM A.date_applied),
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.date_applied)
order by EXTRACT(Year FROM A.date_applied);
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

But I want the output as follows if there is no data available for the particular month it should display as 0.

If there is no data available for a month it should add the month and display the output as 0 from that month

Comment: Please try to better format you code; also, you missed the output. Please have a look at how to build a [mcve]

Comment: You really need to at least show us the current output.  I don't think your question is currently answerable, not even by Gordon Linoff.

Comment: You're already handling `NULL` values with `NVL`, so I would assume that your actual problem is that certain months are completely missing data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why not, I think I succeeded in that mission :)

Comment: Now can you check the image which i am getting output

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PARTITION OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT i.year,
       m.month,
       NVL( i.value, 0 ) AS value
FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL AS month
         FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
       ) m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date_applied ) AS year,
                EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_applied ) AS month,
                ROUND( SUM(
                  NVL( DECODE( direction, '+', ( quantity-qty_reversed)*cost) ), 0 )
                ) ) AS value
         FROM   INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST2
         GROUP BY EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date_applied ),
                EXTRACT( MONTH FROM date_applied )
       ) i
       PARTITION BY ( i.year, m.month )
       ON ( i.month = m.month )
ORDER BY i.year, m.month;
```

Comment: Hey its working fine with only one small modification in PARTITIONBY i removed the month